# Why are records dropping from my left join despite me including null in the where clause

Tags: sql, database, hive, left-join, hiveql

I run the following query:

```
create table c.hello as
select a.*, b.timestamp, b.alert 
from nice a
left join bye b 
  on a.number = b.number_nb 
where (Unix_Timestamp(a.time) - Unix_Timestamp(b.timestamp) >= 0)
  and (Unix_Timestamp(a.time) - Unix_Timestamp(b.timestamp) <= 86400) 
   or b.alert_timestamp is null;
```

Why does my hello table return less records then my nice table has? How can I fix this problem, I want all the records from table nice to be preserved. I thought my OR statement in the where clause would handle that, not sure why it does not. I am aware of the fact that a where clause converts the query to an inner join however I would think that there OR clause with is null should fix that issue. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Because you placed a condition in the `WHERE` clause, and that is filtering out rows.

Place that condition as part of the `JOIN` predicate, as in:

```
create table c.hello as
select a.*, b.timestamp, b.alert 
from nice a
left join bye b 
  on a.number = b.number_nb 
 and (Unix_Timestamp(a.time) - Unix_Timestamp(b.timestamp) >= 0)
 and (Unix_Timestamp(a.time) - Unix_Timestamp(b.timestamp) <= 86400) 
  or b.alert_timestamp is null;
```

Do you see the difference?

Comment: when I do that, it gives me: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10019]: line 20:3 OR not supported in JOIN currently 'alert_timestamp'

Comment: You added the tag for "hive". Hive implements only a small subset of SQL, not the full extent of it.

Comment: yep I am doing it in Hive, and what do you suggest in that case, how can this be done in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

You would fix the problem by moving the relevant conditions to the `ON` clause:

```
create table c.hello as
    select a.*, b.timestamp, b.alert 
    from nice a left join
         bye b 
         on a.number = b.number_nb and
            (Unix_Timestamp(a.time) - Unix_Timestamp(b.timestamp) >= 0) and
            (Unix_Timestamp(a.time) - Unix_Timestamp(b.timestamp) <= 86400) ;
```

The reason your code fails is because some rows in `a` have matching rows in `b` that do not meet either of the timing conditions.  So, the two time constraints are not met.  And the value is not `null` because there are matching rows.

Comment: When I do that, that just gives me: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: line 19:44 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '0'

Comment: any ideas on what I can do in that case?

Comment: @mathlover . . . That would appear to be a peculiarity of Hive.  I'm not sure of a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Having some minimal reproducible example always helps. Let's consider the following example:

```
with A as (
select stack (3,
1, '2019-11-10 10:10:10.000',
2, '2019-12-10 10:10:10.000',
4, '2019-25-10 10:10:10.000'
) as (number_nb,ts)
),

B as (
select stack (2,
1, '2019-11-10 10:10:10.000',
2, '2019-25-10 10:10:10.000' --big difference in timestamp here
) as (number_nb,ts)
)

select a_number_nb, a_ts, 
       b_number_nb, b_ts,
       ts_diff
from
(
select a.number_nb as a_number_nb,a.ts as a_ts, b.number_nb as b_number_nb, b.ts as b_ts, Unix_Timestamp(a.ts) - Unix_Timestamp(b.ts) as ts_diff  
  from A a 
       left join B b on a.number_nb=b.number_nb
)s;
```

Returns:

```
a_number_nb a_ts                    b_number_nb b_ts                    ts_diff
1           2019-11-10 10:10:10.000 1           2019-11-10 10:10:10.000 0
2           2019-12-10 10:10:10.000 2           2019-25-10 10:10:10.000 -34300800
4           2019-25-10 10:10:10.000 NULL        NULL                    NULL
```

Now if you add WHERE clause

```
where (ts_diff between 0 and 86400) or b_number_nb is NULL
```

or even this one:

```
where (ts_diff between 0 and 86400) or ts_diff is NULL
```

The result is:

```
a_number_nb a_ts                    b_number_nb b_ts                    ts_diff
1           2019-11-10 10:10:10.000 1           2019-11-10 10:10:10.000 0
4           2019-25-10 10:10:10.000 NULL        NULL                    NULL
```

Second row is filtered out because the (ts_diff between 0 and 86400) is not met.

If you actually want this result:

```
a_number_nb a_ts                    b_number_nb b_ts
1           2019-11-10 10:10:10.000 1           2019-11-10 10:10:10.000
2           2019-12-10 10:10:10.000 NULL        NULL
4           2019-25-10 10:10:10.000 NULL        NULL
```

Then remove WHERE condition, use case statements instead:

```
... --Use same CTEs as in first example, skipped

select a_number_nb, a_ts, 
       case when (ts_diff between 0 and 86400) then b_number_nb end b_number_nb , --NULL if ts_diff NOT between 0 and 86400
       case when (ts_diff between 0 and 86400) then b_ts        end b_ts
       --ts_diff
from
(
select a.number_nb as a_number_nb,a.ts as a_ts, b.number_nb as b_number_nb, b.ts as b_ts, Unix_Timestamp(a.ts) - Unix_Timestamp(b.ts) as ts_diff  
  from A a 
       left join B b on a.number_nb=b.number_nb
)s
```